# Remover imagem de destaque do post

Tags: wordpress

Como faço para remover a imagem em destaque de uma publicação (imagem postada na postagem) sem removê-la da página inicial do site?

Nota: Tenho um site de imagens com citações e isso é altamente problemático porque desencoraja a publicação e ainda repete a mesma mensagem na imagem duas vezes na página.

Depois de consultar respostas para um problema semelhante, que dizia que o single.php do site deveria ser encontrado e remover algumas linhas, eu abrir um novo problema:

O tema Neutro wordpress que eu uso não possui single.php.

Alguma dicas?

Exemplo (minha página inicial) [LINK](https://sentimentodigital.com/)

página com publicação e exemplo de imagem destacada [exemplo](https://sentimentodigital.com/mensagens-lindas/sonhe/)

Answer (score 1):

Você deve verificar o tipo de post selecionado na pagina de edição do post.

Caso ele seja um post padrão, você deve editar o arquivo "content.php" a imagem se encontra na linha 21.

Remova o código:

```html
<?php if ( (function_exists('neutro_has_get_the_image') ? neutro_has_get_the_image() : '' ) ) if (comments_open() && !post_password_required()) 
    comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%','comment-counter'); ?>

    <?php $featured_image = neutro_featured_image_widths();
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'get-the-image' ) ) get_the_image( array( 'size' => $featured_image['size'], 'width' => $featured_image['width'], 'height' => $featured_image['height'], 'image_class' => 'featured-thumbnail', 'before' => '<figure>', 'after' => '</figure>' ) ); ?>
```

outros arquivos como:
content-aside.php
content-audio.php
content-status.php e etc...
Também podem conter esse mesmo código que puxa uma imagem destacada.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, sua dica funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Obrigado vote na minha resposta.